# CodeIgniter and PostgreSQL - Retrieving data from Function returning refcursor

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, ref-cursor

I have a PostgreSQL function that selects data and returns it via a refcursor, similar to the following declaration:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
  RETURNS refcursor AS
  ...
```

How do I retrieve data from this function via a CodeIgniter model? I can't just SELECT directly from the function as it does not return the data directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, a post on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php) gave the following solution:

```
protected function dbquery($query){
  pg_query("BEGIN;");
  $tr=pg_query($query);
  $r=pg_fetch_row($tr);
  $name=$r[0];
  $rs=pg_query("FETCH ALL IN \"" . $name . "\";");
  pg_query("END;");
  return $rs;
}
```

Which can be wired up in the model as follows:

```
$query = $this->dbquery("SELECT * FROM my_function()");

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   array_push($result, array('my_column' => $row['my_column'] ));
}
```

Not an ideal solution as it does not use the CI Postgres driver's functions (although it probably could be refactored to), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above does not take advantage of the CI active record class.  To do this in CI just run a custom query.

For example:

```
$sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION... "
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Agreed, but I was not trying to `CREATE` the function. The function returns a cursor and I needed to call that function and read the data that it returns. If you can post an example of doing *that* using CI's active record class, I would be grateful.